# Как реализовать параллельный скролл в блоке?

Tags: javascript, события, прокрутка

Коллеги, прошу вас помочь мне разобраться со скроллом меню, параллельно со скроллом окна.

САБЖ:
Есть лайаут у которого есть ДЛИННОЕ сайдебар меню, упакованное в блок, который позволяет его скроллить.
При скролле окна, после шапки, сайдебвр прилепает к его верху и начинает скроллится сам.

ПРОБЛЕМА:
Если мы захотим сами, руками, проскроллить сайдебар, а потом вернемся к скроллу окна - сайдебар "подпрыгнет" на координату скролла у окна, что естественно.

НАДО:
Запомнить **куда был проскроллен сайдебар пользователем**, и начинать скролл именно с этой позиции, если есть куда скроллить, т.е. высота сайдебара еще не вся.

**В обратную сторону, т.е. при скролле окна наверх, тоже должно работать.**

НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ адекватно придумать логику этого действа. Прошу вас помочь.

[Вот ссылка на песочницу](https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/xxmmZwN)

```js
const header = document.querySelector(".header");
const aside = document.querySelector(".aside");
const sidebarScroller = document.querySelector(".sidebar__scroller");
const sidebarContent = document.querySelector(".inner");

const main = document.querySelector(".main");

let headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;
let sidebarScrollerScrollHeight = sidebarScroller.scrollHeight;
let contentHeight = sidebarContent.offsetHeight;

let style =
  sidebarScroller.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(sidebarScroller);
let size = parseInt(style.paddingBottom);

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY > headerHeight) {
    sidebarScroller.scrollTop = window.scrollY - headerHeight;
    console.log(sidebarContent.scrollTop);
    sidebarScroller.classList.add("132");
  } else {
    sidebarScroller.classList.remove("132");
  }
});

//https://medium.com/@humbleCoder007/title-mastering-window-scroll-events-in-javascript-416607be8852
```

```css
.header {
  height: 145px;
  background-color: #f0f;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  width: max(320px, 80%);
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.sidebar__scroller {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0ff;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /**/
  /* margin-bottom: 160px; */
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.inner {
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #ff0;
  height: 200px;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>logo</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="container">
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar__scroller">
        <div class="inner">
          <h2>Какой-то очень длинный список меню, который скроллиться вместе с окном, сразу после шапки</h2>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quidem minima quos tenetur asperiores, alias odit ex, ipsam cum blanditiis dolorum vel expedita. Delectus mollitia magni deleniti quidem omnis inventore nemo? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipisicing elit. Sapiente, cumque. Fugit amet perferendis minima, ipsa expedita tempora rem accusantium consequuntur cumque quidem odio esse vel voluptas ab error ratione omnis.
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <main class="main">
      <h2>Какой-то длинный конент, который просто скроллиться</h2>
    </main>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</div>
```